# Google load balancer latency to backend

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-cloud-cdn

I have set up a HTTP(S) load balancer and activated Cloud CDN. This sits in front of an instance group containing just 1 instance which is located in australia-southeast.

Connecting to the CDN IP does route the user to the closest POP. The challenge I face, however, is that when cache misses occur, the path back to the VM from the CDN seems to have a fair bit of latency which then gets passed onto the user, somewhat defeating the purpose.

Output of ping from VM:

```
tristan@tabletop-web:~$ ping 35.227.XX.XX
PING 35.227.XX.XX (35.227.XX.XX) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=6 ttl=48 time=128 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=7 ttl=48 time=128 ms
^C
--- 35.227.XX.XX ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 128.099/128.237/128.506/0.231 ms
```

I would have thought the latency between VM and CDN would be <1ms as it is when connecting from another VM (different provider) in the same physical location:

```
tristan@syd:~$ ping 35.227.XX.XX
PING 35.227.XX.XX(35.227.XX.XX) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=1.06 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=1.06 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=1.04 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=1.04 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=1.03 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=1.11 ms
64 bytes from 35.227.XX.XX: icmp_seq=8 ttl=56 time=1.05 ms

--- 35.227.XX.XX ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.038/1.063/1.113/0.036 ms
tristan@syd:~$
```

Has anyone experienced this and know of a solution?

Cheers